Primereact password component width doesn't fit container
I am new to React and I started working on a Sign up page, I am trying to make the password fit the container but it doesn't seem to make a difference no matter which method I try, Is there even a way to change the width of Primereact password component?
This is the full code of my page:
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Password } from 'primereact/password';
import { FaCheckCircle } from 'react-icons/fa';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { ClipLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import styles from '../styles/AuthPage.module.css';
import { useFormValidator } from '../hooks/useFormValidator';

function SignUpPage() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });
  const { errors, validateForm, onBlurField } = useFormValidator(form);
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const emailRef = useRef(null);
  const passwordRef = useRef(null);

  const onUpdateField = e => {
    const field = e.target.name;
    const nextFormState = {
      ...form,
      [field]: e.target.value,
    };
    setForm(nextFormState);
    if (errors[field].dirty)
      validateForm({
        form: nextFormState,
        errors,
        field,
      });
  };

  const focusFirstErrorField = () => {
    if (errors.email.dirty && errors.email.error) {
      emailRef.current.focus();
    } else if (errors.password.dirty && errors.password.error) {
      passwordRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Tab' && e.target.name === 'email') {
      e.preventDefault();
      passwordRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError('');
    setSuccessMessage('');

    const { isValid } = validateForm({ form, errors, forceTouchErrors: true });
    if (!isValid) {
      focusFirstErrorField();
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/signup', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: form.email, password: form.password }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        setError(errorData.errors ? errorData.errors.map(e => e.msg).join(', ') : 'Failed to create an account');
        setIsLoading(false);
        focusFirstErrorField();
        return;
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('Sign up successful:', data);
      setSuccessMessage('Sign up successful! You can now log in.');
      setForm({ email: '', password: '' });
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setError('Failed to create an account. Please try again later.');
      console.error('Failed to create an account', error);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.authPage}>
      <h2>Sign Up</h2>
      <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className={styles.formGroup}>
          <label className={styles.formLabel}>Email</label>
          <input
            className={clsx(
              styles.formField,
              errors.email.dirty && errors.email.error && styles.error
            )}
            type="text"
            aria-label="Email field"
            name="email"
            value={form.email}
            onChange={onUpdateField}
            onBlur={onBlurField}
            ref={emailRef}
            onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
            tabIndex={1}
          />
          {errors.email.dirty && errors.email.error && (
            <p className={styles.error}>
              {errors.email.message}
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.formGroup}>
          <label className={styles.formLabel}>Password</label>
          <Password
            className={clsx(
              styles.formField,
              errors.password.dirty && errors.password.error && styles.error
            )}
            aria-label="Password field"
            name="password"
            value={form.password}
            onChange={onUpdateField}
            onBlur={onBlurField}
            feedback={true}
            toggleMask
            inputStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
            ref={passwordRef}
          />
          {errors.password.dirty && errors.password.error && (
            <p className={styles.error}>
              {errors.password.message}
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.formActions} tabIndex={2}>
          <button className={styles.formSubmitBtn} type="submit" disabled={isLoading}>
            {isLoading ? 'Signing Up...' : 'Sign Up'}
          </button>
        </div>
        {isLoading && (
          <div className={styles.loadingSpinner}>
            <ClipLoader size={35} color={"#007bff"} loading={isLoading} />
          </div>
        )}
        {successMessage && (
          <div className={styles.successMessage}>
            <FaCheckCircle className={styles.checkIcon} /> {successMessage}
          </div>
        )}
        {error && <div className={styles.error}>{error}</div>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SignUpPage;

I have tried Inline styling with inputstyle, style and I've tried to style the class from the css but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?
Update:
I have tried applying the solution for making the password fit the container without using PrimeFlex as suggested by @Kyle
Code:
<div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%' }} className={styles.formGroup}>
      <label className={styles.formLabel}>Password</label>
      <Password
        inputStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
        pt={{ iconField: { style: { width: '100%' } }, input: { style: { width: '100%' } } }}
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        className={clsx(
          styles.formField,
          errors.password.dirty && errors.password.error && styles.error
        )}
        aria-label="Password field"
        name="password"
        value={form.password}
        onChange={onUpdateField}
        onBlur={onBlurField}
        feedback={true}
        toggleMask
        ref={passwordRef}
      />
      {errors.password.dirty && errors.password.error && (
        <p className={styles.error}>{errors.password.message}</p>
      )}
    </div>

Output:

And when i remove the style to the div container in order to get the password on top of the field this happens:


Prime react has a few different ways you can edit the style of the component.
You can use className, style or passthroughs (pt)
The first approach and primary approach that I suggest is via className or style prop....if you are using prime flex then you can simply pass the width such as w-full or w-10rem etc in the class name...this is the primary way my team does this. If you do not use prime flex then you can simply use the style prop which takes typical inline css
example:
<Password style={{width:'10rem'}}/>
OR primeFlex:
<Password className='w-10rem'/>

However there are some circumstances that require a bit more style control in which cases you can use passthroughs (pt prop) which if you go to the documentation you can easily see how to style it

Here is how you can do this (with prime flex / 100% width)
Link to sandbox
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Password } from 'primereact/password';

export default function PasswordFullWidthDemo() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className=" flex justify-content-center w-full">
      <Password
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        className="w-full"
        pt={{ input: { className: 'w-full' } }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


Without Prime Flex:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Password } from 'primereact/password';

export default function PasswordFullWidthDemo() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%' }}>
      <Password
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        pt={{ input: { style: { width: '100%' } } }}
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}



Hey Kyle, thanks for the suggestions, I am not using Prime Flex in my project, I have imported the password component from Prime React. I tried using the style prop method to no avail, I have not tried using passthroughs though so I'll give it a shot. thanks!

I have tried using passthroughs to apply styling to the specific component which is iconField in my case but it did not work, I tried to change the HTML on my page through inspect element and when i set the width of this specific flex item (i.e p-icon-field class), the password field width was taking up the full width of the container. here's the code I used for passthroughs

<Password     inputStyle={{ width: "100%" }}       pt={{        iconField: { style: { width: "100%" } },       }}       className={clsx(         styles.formField,         errors.password.dirty && errors.password.error && styles.error        )}        aria-label="Password field"        name="password"        value={form.password}        onChange={onUpdateField}        onBlur={onBlurField}        feedback={true}        toggleMask        ref={passwordRef} />

just to double check: all youre trying to do is get the password component fit into its container or something else? I can spin up a sandbox to help

I updated my answer and created a stackblitz sandbox for you to check out that makes the password component fill its parent size. let me know if this helps or if you are trying to do something else

I am just trying to make the password component fit the container's full width.
I have gone through you updated answer and tried to apply pt and classname to my password component but it did not work. could you please consider going through my question code snippet for context.

have you checked out the sandbox? if youre not using prime flex then instead of classname you would do style & width (i updated the answer again with the non-prime flex version) PS prime flex makes things really nice and easy if youre interested its just a css lib that lets you apply styles easy via classnames instead of css files or inline etc

I have tried applying your solution for making the password field fit the container width without using Prime Flex but the password field just gets aligned to the left side without actually increasing the width. I will try to share a screenshot in the updated question please check it out.

Then there must be some other styling applied by your code that is messing with it because as you can see from the sandbox, this is the correct solution - it is hard for me to know what is going on without having a public url for me to look at for your application. Maybe try removing the class names

I faced the same error. When you're adding the toggleMask prop the width will not fit. It took me time to figure out, but when you add this code
.p-icon-field {
  width: 100%;
}

in your global CSS and apply the inputStyle={{ width: '100%' }} on your Password component your problem will be fixed. At least it worked for me

I faced the same error as @Attila Gyén with the icon field when using the ToggleMask, but there's another way to solve the same thing without going directly to the .p-icon-field class by using the passthrough options offered by primereact:
 <Password
        pt={{
          iconField: {
            root: {
              style: { width: "100%" },
            },
          },
          input: {
            style: { width: "100%" },
          },
          root: {
            style: { width: "100%" },
          },
        }}
      />

Remember this code my seem complex, but it lets you customize the classes already given by primereact in your JSX / TSX side of the code.
